# Where should I open / close JMS connections in a JSF ManagedBean?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, jms, managed-bean

In a simple demo web app using JSF 2 and Ajax, there is a method in the ManagedBean which receives messages from a JMS queue:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean {

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/HabariConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/TOOL.DEFAULT")
    private Queue queue;

    public String getMessage() {
        String result = "no message";
        try {
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
            Message message = consumer.receiveNoWait();
            if (message != null) {
                result = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
            }
            connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Bean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
         return result;
    }
}
```

The JMS connection is opened / closed every time the getMessage() method is invoked. Which options do I have to open and close the JMS connection only once in the bean life cycle, to avoid frequent connect/disconnect operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, move your `Connection` to be a instance variable so that it can be accessed from your open, close, and `getMessage` methods.

Next, create an `openConnection` method with the `PostConstruct` annotation.

```
@PostConstruct
public void openConnection() {
    connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
}
```

Finally, create a `closeConnection` method with the `PreDestroy` annotation.

```
@PreDestroy
public void closeConnection() {
    connection.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about in the servlet context listener?

Just define in web.xml

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>contextListenerClass</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And then implement a servletContextListener

```
public final class contextListenerClassimplements ServletContextListener {
...
}
```

Other solution can be to use SessionListener...