# Lifecycle of MQ Connection in JSF - Connection Closed

Tags: jsf-2, jms, mq

I use JSF 2 an WebSphere MQ for Messaging (JMS).

I want to know what's the best practice to open / close the QueueConnection?
Should I use for each client session one connection and open it on (post-)construction and close it on (pre-) destruction like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870342/where-should-i-open-close-jms-connections-in-a-jsf-managedbean)?

Or are there better ways to handle the connection? E.g. ["Open EntityManager in View"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607664/how-to-use-openjpa-entitymanagerfactory-in-jsf) Pattern for JDBC/JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid creating a new connection for each `getMessage()` invocation. Create one connection at construct time, save it as an instance variable.

For each `getMessage()` call, create a new session, get the message, then close the session.

When you're done, close the connection at destruction time.